# Mac Overheating Problems and Fan Noise

Tags: mac, snow-leopard, temperature

I have a old MB, which has Snow Leopard 10.6 Installed onto it. How can I fix the overheating and that fan noise? Whenever i open a large file or like install Windows 7 from Bootcamp, it would overheat and make some wind noises from the fan. It's a preety fast mac, i installed new RAM and just newly installed SL onto it. Can someone help me?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I would do is open up the case and use a can of air to blow out all the dust bunnies that have likely accumulated since the Macbook was first put into service; that will probably help quite a bit.

Comment: Glad to have helped.